# HTML 5- How to prevent email validation from input box from type='email'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, angularjs

on submit button when invalid email don't get email address on alert in controller.js file

also used the @scope

```
<form ng-show="!subscribeSuccess" ng-submit="subscribeNewsLetter(subscribEmailAddress)" novalidate>
<input type="email" name="subscribEmailAddress" placeholder="SHOP.SUBSCRIBE_PLACEHOLDER" ng-            model="subscribEmailAddress" translate>
<button type="submit" name="commit" class="action-button" translate>SHOP.SUBSCRIBE</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

use `novalidate` attribute:

```
<input type="email" novalidate/>
```

The `novalidate` attribute simply tells the browser to disable the built-in HTML5 validation, or ignore any HTML5 validation attributes you may have used.

Comment: Whwn I click on submit button, with invalid email, it not display the invalid email-id in browser console , in params also go NULL

Answer (score 0):

disable validation and your email address go to scope

like `<input type="text" />`